# How to check if $PWD is a subdirectory of a given path

Tags: bash, shell, directory, string

E.g. check if `$PWD` is a subdirectory of /home. In other words I'm searching for a bash string operation to check if one string starts with another.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

If you want to reliably test whether a directory is a subdirectory of another, you'll need more than just a string prefix check.  Gilles' answer describes in detail how to do this test properly.

But if you do want a simple string prefix check (maybe you've already normalized your paths?), this is a good one:

```
test "${PWD##/home/}" != "${PWD}"
```

If `$PWD` starts with "/home/", it gets stripped off in the left side, which means it won't match the right side, so "!=" returns true.

Comment: +1 perfect, and for a more general case: `[ "${PWD##$VAR}" != "$PWD" ]` And if this were a [code-golf ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)question you'd have beaten me by two chars ;-) Also it looks more readable...

Comment: FWIW, this may be also useful: `${PWD/#$HOME/\~}`

Comment: Alright, but how about PWD="/home/../etc/"

Comment: @AlexisPeters:  You're right: I was focusing on the "string prefix" part of the question, and I have edited to make that more clear.  Gilles has nicely covered the proper way to check for subdirectories.

Comment: Use `"${PWD%%/subdir*}"` to detect whether the user is currently in `subdir` or in a subdirectory of `subdir`, since %% captures from the end of the string instead of the beginning. This should be useful to anyone looking for more info on parameter substitution: https://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/parameter-substitution.html

Answer (score 60):

To test if a string is a prefix of another, in any Bourne-style shell:

```
case $PWD/ in
  /home/*) echo "home sweet home";;
  *) echo "away from home";;
esac
```

The same principle works for a suffix or substring test. Note that in `case` constructs, unlike in file names, `*` matches any character, including a `/` or an initial `.`.

In shells that implement the `[[ … ]]` syntax (i.e. bash, ksh and zsh), it can be used to match a string against a pattern. (Note that the `[` command can only test strings for equality.)

```
if [[ $PWD/ = /home/* ]]; then …
```

---

If you're specifically testing whether the current directory is underneath `/home`, a simple substring test is not enough, because of symbolic links.

If `/home` is a filesystem of its own, test whether the current directory (`.`) is on that filesystem.

```
if [ "$(df -P . | awk 'NR==2 {print $6}')" = "/home" ]; then
  echo 'The current directory is on the /home filesystem'
fi
```

If you have the NetBSD, OpenBSD or GNU or busybox or toybox `readlink` (the last 3 commonly found on Linux-based systems such as Debian, OpenWrt or Android), you can use `readlink -f` to strip symbolic links from a path.

```
case $(readlink -f .)/ in "$(readlink -f /home)"/*) …
```

Some systems also have a `realpath` command for that (also in the GNU tool chest where it's preferred over `readlink` these days):

```
case $(realpath .)/ in "$(realpath /home)"/*) …
```

The `zsh` shell also has its own `realpath()` operator with the `:P` modifier:

```
if () [[ $1:P/ = $2:P/* ]] . /home; then …
```

Otherwise, you can use `pwd` to show the current directory. But you must take care not to use a shell built-in if your shell tracks `cd` commands and keeps the name you used to reach the directory rather than its “actual” location.

```
case $(pwd -P 2>/dev/null || env PWD= pwd)/ in
  "$(cd /home && { pwd -P 2>/dev/null || env PWD= pwd; })"/*) …
```

Answer (score 12):

Crude version:

```
[ "${PWD:0:6}" = /home/ ]
```

Has the disadvantage that one has to count characters first and one can't replace `/home/` by something general like `$1`.

**edit** (thanks @Michael) for the generalization to compare with `$VAR` one can use

```
[ "${PWD:0:${#VAR}}" = "$VAR" ]
```

Comment: `${#var}` is the length of `$var`, so you can generalize it as `[ "${PWD:0:${#1}}" = "$1" ]`

Comment: Heads up: see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20615217/bash-bad-substitution) if you're getting the *Bad substitution* error

Comment: Also, if you need this in `sh`, not `bash`, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48913862)

Answer (score 6):

You can use gnu `realpath` with the --relative-to or --relative-base parameters, in combination with a string check

```
$ mkdir -p /tmp/a/b/c/d /tmp/a/e/f
$ isSubPath() if [[ $(realpath --relative-base="$1" -- "$2")  =~ ^/ ]]
    then printf '%s\n' "$2 NOT subpath of $1"
    else printf '%s\n' "$2 subpath of $1"
  fi
$ isSubPath /tmp/a/ /tmp/a/e/
/tmp/a/e/ subpath of /tmp/a/
$ isSubPath /tmp/a/ /tmp/a/e/f/
/tmp/a/e/f/ subpath of /tmp/a/
$ isSubPath /tmp/a/b/ /tmp/a/e/f/
/tmp/a/e/f/ NOT subpath of /tmp/a/b/
$ cd /tmp/a/b/c/d/
$ isSubPath . /tmp/a/
/tmp/a/ NOT subpath of .
$ isSubPath /tmp/a/ .
. subpath of /tmp/a/
$ isSubPath /tmp/a/ ../../../
../../../ subpath of /tmp/a
$ isSubPath /tmp/a/ ../../../../../../
../../../../../../ NOT subpath of /tmp/a/
$ isSubPath /tmp/a/ ../../../../../../tmp/a/e/
../../../../../../tmp/a/e/ subpath of /tmp/a/
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't understand the question too well, but to find the parent of **$PWD**, do `dirname -- "$PWD"`. To find the parent of the parent, run `dirname -- "$(dirname -- "$PWD")"`, and so on...

Comment: That would only work if I knew the depth, otherwise I end up with `/`. Ok, I could check recursively, but isn't there something easier?

Answer (score 0):

Hm, it's pity that `[` doesn't have an option of testing `STRING1 starts with STRING2` condition.

You may try `echo $PWD | grep '^$VAR'`, but it can fail in interesting ways when `VAR` contains special symbols.

`awk`'s `index` function should be able to do the trick.  But all this seems just too heavy for such an easy thing to test.

Comment: [[ does regexp so yo get startswith

    [[ $PWD =~ ^\/home\/ ]]

Answer (score 0):

If the searched part of path is found I "empty" the variable :

```
[[ -z "${PWD//*\/home\/*/}" ]] && echo "toto"
```

Answer (score 0):

Combining some of the answers above:

```
$isSubDir () { local sd=$(realpath $1); local d=$(realpath $2); [ "${sd:0:${#d}}" = "$d" ]; echo $?; };
$isSubDir .. .
1
$isSubDir . $HOME
0
```

Answer (score -2):

Using `awk`:

```
echo $PWD | awk -v h="/home" '$0 ~ h {print "MATCH"}'
```

Comment: +1 for working, but a bit slower than a native bash test

Comment: That's just plain wrong. `echo` can't be used for arbitrary data, parameter expansions must be quoted, `~` is for ERE matching not to check whether a string starts with another. `awk` works on one line at a time an a path can be made of several, `-v` mangles backslashes.